# custom post type does not working when adding in child theme function

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, child-theme

I'm trying to register post type through child theme `function.php` but it does not working. However its working fine when i adding in the parent `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'testimonial' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'testimonial' ) ) :
function testimonial() {
    register_post_type( 'testimonial',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Testimonial',
                'singular_name' => 'Testimonial',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Testimonial',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Testimonial',
                'new_item' => 'New Testimonial',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Testimonial',
                'search_items' => 'Search Testimonial',
                'not_found' => 'No Testimonial found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Testimonial found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Testimonial'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            //'menu_icon' => 'T',
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url().'/images/testimonial.png',
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
endif;
```

Can any one guide me is this possible that i can register post_type through child theme `function.php` ? I will appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to check you functions. That function might exist somewhere in your code.
if you cant find it, then try to remove the `if` statement and just add your function directly like this

```
function testimonial() {
    register_post_type( 'testimonial',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Testimonial',
                'singular_name' => 'Testimonial',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Testimonial',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Testimonial',
                'new_item' => 'New Testimonial',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Testimonial',
                'search_items' => 'Search Testimonial',
                'not_found' => 'No Testimonial found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Testimonial found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Testimonial'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            //'menu_icon' => 'T',
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url().'/images/testimonial.png',
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'testimonial' );
```